# sql array string is not unserializing (properly, at least?)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, serialization

I have a column in my sql table for sizes, and it's supposed to be a drop down menu that displays the sizes and then links you to a new sql row; however, nothing shows up in the options box and there's nothing displayed in the source code. This is what the code looks like:

```
<form>
     <select onchange="window.location.href=this.form.URL.options[this.form.URL.selectedIndex].value" name="URL">
        <?php
          $size = unserialize($row['size']);
          foreach ($size as $key => $value) {
               echo "<option value='$value'>$key</option>\n";
          }
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

My arrays look as such:

```
"a:12:{s:3:"1/8";s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101300";s:3:"1
/4";s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101101";s:3:"3
/8";s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101102";s:3:"1
/2";s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101023";s:3:"3
/4";s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101024";s:1:"1";
s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101025";s:5:"1 
1/4";s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101026";s:5:"1 
1/2";s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101027";s:1:"2";
s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101028";s:5:"2 
1/2";s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101109";s:1:"3";
s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101110";s:1:"4";
s:27:"legendproduct.php?id=101111";}"
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is that your actual serialized array format? The outer `" "` and all the line returns would be a syntax error, I believe. Wrapping in `' '` and it all it one line, your code works fine here - http://3v4l.org/ZYgFl

Comment: the outer quotes/returns weren't part of my string, but I realized my length allotment was too short, cutting off the end of the string. oops. thanks for the input anyway!